# Snakemake: do not resolve wildcards in input

Tags: python, snakemake

I want to use a pipeline that requires an `*` and `R{1,2}` in the input string.

```
rule preprocess:
    input:
        reads = '{WORKDIR}/*/*R{1,2}.fastq.gz'
    output:
        bam = '{WORKDIR}/mapping/bwa/{sample}.bam'
    shell:
        "nextflow run somePipeline "
        "--reads '{input.reads}' "
```

The final shell command should be:
`nextflow run somePipeline --reads 'work_dir/main_sample_folder/*/*R{1,2}.fastq.gz'`

However, Snakemake thinks 'R{1,2} is a wildcard and produces the following error:

```
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'1'
```

I've tried escaping the curly brackets with double curly brackets `R{{1,2}}` and with backslash `R\{1,2\}`, but it did not work.

How to escape `R{1,2}` part of the input, so that Snakemake does not think this is a wildcard, rather a part of the string?

Comment: Could you make a minimal example?

Comment: The input section of a snakemake rule needs actual paths to files. I think you will have to construct a list of the files corresponding to your pattern to feed the input of your rule. But in the shell section, you do not necessarily need to explicitly refer to the input of the rule. You might be able to use something like "work_dir/main_sample_folder/*/*R{{1,2}}.fastq.gz" (the double curly braces "escape" them from Python/Snakemake string interpolation so that the shell sees single curly braces).